# Convergence of infinite series of function with factorial and power

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

Determine whether the series is convergent or divergent:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(3n)!+4^{n+1}}{(3n+2)!}$$

I guess we have to use comparison test for this question, but I am not sure what to use for comparison, anyone can help with clear explanation why it is used?

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(3n)!+4^{n+1}}{(3n+2)!} & = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(3n+1)(3n+2)}+ 4 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{4^n}{(3n+2)!}\\
& \le \frac 19 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} + 4 \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{4^n}{5^n} = \frac{\pi^2}{54} + 20.
\end{align}

I have used the following facts: $(3n+1)(3n+2) > 9n^2$, $5^n < (3n+2)!$ for $n \ge 0$. Both are obviouse, you can prove the second one by induction.